# How to use "&" in Menu Items (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, menuitem, hotkeys, menubar

I don't know what is "&" called, but I want to add to a WPF menu item like this `&Search` so when we hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, a small line will appear under "S".

See picture below:

[image]

Comment: The &-sign is called ampersand. But for WPF you use the _ character as already been answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called an accelerator key. In WPF it's used by the `_` character prefix.

For example: `_Search`, `Hel_p Favorites`, etc.